# Arrival and departure date records of people entering and departing France

Tags: france

The US Department of Homeland Security provides [online access](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/request.html) to arrival and departure date records of nonimmigrant aliens entering and departing the United States.

Do some French agency provide the same for people entering and departing France?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This information is not recorded. To boot, you are not crossing the French border, you are crossing the Schengen border. From an [EU memo](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_MEMO-13-141_en.htm):

> There are already measures and tools available at EU border crossing points, such as the Schengen Information System (SIS) and Visa Information System (VIS). However, none is intended for the purpose of recording border crossings

Comment: Even if there is not yet a Schengen wide database for entries and exits, your answer is not generally valid for all Schengen countries. Several Schengen states record border crossings in own national database: "as of February 2013, ... Estonia, Finland, Greece, Hungary, Latvia, Lithuania, Malta, Poland, Portugal, Slovakia and Spain record third-country nationals' entries and exits in their national databases" (source: Wikipedia).

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo But your list confirms it's not recorded in France, which is what the question was about…

Comment: @Relaxed: The list is two years old and since the planning of a Schengen wide EES (Entry Exit System) is ongoing, I would not rule out that other Schengen countries are preparing the introduction by first introducing national systems. My point however was that "you are not crossing the French border" is a too far reaching statement. Even if France is a Schengen member, it has of course partial souvereignity of its borders and may record entries and exits as long as the data collection does not violate the Schengen regulations (which is does not).

Comment: Even if the answer should be correct, the entire explanation is wrong.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That's a particularly uncharitable way to read the answer, “to boot“ does not seem to imply any sort of causality between the two points. But what I am saying is merely that it would have been more constructive to phrase your comment as a useful addition rather than a criticism.

Comment: Why would chx add a lot of irrelevant information in his answer, if he didn't mean to imply that it is related to the question? "This information is not recorded." is probably correct. The rest of the paragraph ("you are not crossing the French border") is wrong and the quote from the EU memo is taken out of context and for the question actually completely irrelevant. Even if SIS and VIS are not intended to record border crossings, the statement does not reject the possibility that other systems are used at the border to record exits and entries.